# Prove that if a and b are integers such that $7$ divides $a^2 + b^2$ , then $7$ divides $a^2$ and $7$ divides $b^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Trying to learn how to approach proofs. This seems easy enough, assuming I should be using the division algorithm but not sure how to start.

Comment: Well, $a^2\equiv0,1,2,4\bmod7$...

Answer (score 3):

Step one:  Show that upon division by 7, a square has remainder $0, 1, 2,$ or $4$.

Step two:  Try to get two of those remainders to add to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do these things is to consider if $a \equiv m \pmod 7$ and $b\equiv n\pmod 7$ where $m,n$ are basic representations in a "reduced residue system" then what are the possible values of $a^2 + b^2 \equiv m^2 + n^2 \pmod 7$?

Although the first reduce residue system we learn is $0,....., 6$ it is probably more convient and use for to consider the system $0, 1,2,3, -1(\equiv 6), -2(\equiv 5), -3(\equiv 6)$.

In other words:

If $7|a^2 + b^2$ then $a^2 + b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$.

So $b^2 \equiv -(a^2)\pmod 7$.

Now there are only $7$ values that consider for $a\pmod 7$.

$a \equiv 0, \pm 1, \pm 2,$ or $\pm 3 \pmod 7$.

And that results in $4$ values for $a^2$; $a^2 \equiv 0, 1, 4, 9$ or in other words $0,1,-3,2\pmod 7$.

This are the only four possible equivalences for square integers.  If $n^2$ is a square integer then $n^2 \equiv 0,1,-3, 2\pmod 7$ and $n^2 \not \equiv 3,-1,-2\pmod 7$.

And if $a^2 \equiv 0,1,-3,2$  that means $b^2 \equiv -a^2 \equiv 0, -1, 3,-2 \pmod 7$.

But $b^2$ is a square and so $b^2 \equiv 0,1,-3,$ or $2$ and it is not possible that $b^2 \equiv -1,3,$ or $-2$.

So the only possible option is $b^2 \equiv 0$ and $b\equiv 0\pmod 7$ and that can only happen if $a \equiv 0 \pmod 7$.

So $a,b \equiv 0\pmod 7$

which means $7|a$ and $7|b$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *law of quadratic reciprocity* and its first supplement:
 if $a^2+b^2\equiv 0\bmod 7$ and one of $a^2, b^2\not\equiv 0 \bmod7$, i would imply that $-1$ has a square root mod. $7$. For instance, if $a^2\ne 0$, $a$  has an inverse mod. $7$ and we would have $\;1+(a^{-1}b)^2\equiv 0$.

However, as $7\equiv 3\mod 4$, the first supplement says this is impossible.